# WordPress 5.2.1 deactivated my jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been using the code below to use Google's jQuery but the latest WordPress version deactivated it. How can I use jQuery from Google?

```
//* Use Google's jQuery
add_action('init', 'use_jquery_from_google');

function use_jquery_from_google () {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_scripts;
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
        $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
    } else {
        $ver = '3.4.0';
    }

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure using the Google CDN is actually faster?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. It was just something that was suggested. Are you saying I shouldn't use the Google CDN?

Comment: @Desi sometimes it's faster, sometimes it isn't, but it's almost universally parrotted as a bonus without anybody ever testing if it improves things. As for 5.2, there's nothing in 5.2 that would stop this from working that I know of. jquery-core lists jquery as a dependent anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

5.2.1 includes a backported fix from jQuery 3.4.0 ([commit](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/4ce6eb57b60055636077f2879256b78d169456c1)). Because they're now using a modified version of jQuery they suffixed the version number with '-wp':

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4-wp' );
```

Your code tries to copy the jQuery version number from the existing registration

```
global $wp_scripts;
if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
    $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
```

The problem is that Google's CDN won't have a version of jQuery called 1.12.4-wp. The following URL

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4-wp/jquery.min.js
```

doesn't exist. The same URL without the '-wp' does work. So the error you should be seeing in your browser console is a 404 loading jQuery from the CDN.

The jQuery patch is to fix [Trac 47020](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47020) which is a security issue in jQuery.extend that could allow cross-site scripting attacks (["Minor vulnerability fix: Object.prototype pollution"](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/)). So you probably do want it, either by using WordPress's patched version of 1.2.14 again or by updating to 3.4.0 (if that's compatible with the rest of your site).